# Tikz misaligning edge starting point on matrix of math nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I just noticed that this commutative diagram had the initial vertex of the edge creep up into my first node.  Is there an obvious way to fix this?

Here is the code for an MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (b) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
  column sep=3em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex]
  { \left( \lim\limits_{[t]\in \Theta[C]\downarrow X} E_[t]\right)(x,y) & E_X(x,y) \\
  \left( \lim\limits_{[t]\in\Theta[C]\downarrow X} \mathfrak{C}([t])\right)(x,y) &  \mathfrak{C}(X)(x,y) \\};
  \path[->, font=\scriptsize]
  (b-1-1) edge (b-1-2)
          edge node[auto,swap]{\(\scriptstyle \cong\)} (b-2-1)
  (b-2-1) edge (b-2-2)
  (b-1-2) edge (b-2-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}.
  \end{equation*}
  \end{document}
```

and here is the screenshot:
[image: weird commutative diagram]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. It's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from. Btw, to highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a fixed text height and text depth, that's why the nodes become too small to fit the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (b) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
  column sep=3em]
  { \left( \lim\limits_{[t]\in \Theta[C]\downarrow X} E_[t]\right)(x,y) & E_X(x,y) \\
  \left( \lim\limits_{[t]\in\Theta[C]\downarrow X} \mathfrak{C}([t])\right)(x,y) &  \mathfrak{C}(X)(x,y) \\};
  \path[->, font=\scriptsize]
  (b-1-1) edge (b-1-2)
          edge node[auto,swap]{\(\scriptstyle \cong\)} (b-2-1)
  (b-2-1) edge [-,double] (b-2-2)
  (b-1-2) edge (b-2-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}.
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for completeness: you can draw the thing very conveniently with the `tikz-cd` package. I am also "outsourcing" the double line. This is not really necessary here, one could draw it in the commutative diagram, but this is to tell you how you could add "ordinary" Ti*k*Z paths to a commutative diagram without much pain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
\left( \lim\limits_{[t]\in \Theta[C]\downarrow X} E_[t]\right)(x,y) \ar[r] 
\ar[d,"\cong"]
& E_X(x,y) \ar[d] \\
\left( \lim\limits_{[t]\in\Theta[C]\downarrow X} \mathfrak{C}([t])\right)(x,y) &  \mathfrak{C}(X)(x,y) \\
\end{tikzcd}  
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[double] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) --
(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2);}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]